# Undefined offset PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

Hello I have a code that checks for duplicates inside an xml file:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<profielen>
    <profiel>
        <voornaam>a</voornaam>
        <achternaam>a</achternaam>
        <adres>a</adres>
        <postcode>a</postcode>
        <plaats>a</plaats>
        <email>a</email>
    </profiel>
    <profiel>
        <voornaam>b</voornaam>
        <achternaam>b</achternaam>
        <adres>b</adres>
        <postcode>b</postcode>
        <plaats>b</plaats>
        <email>b</email>
    </profiel>
    <profiel>
        <voornaam>c</voornaam>
        <achternaam>c</achternaam>
        <adres>c</adres>
        <postcode>c</postcode>
        <plaats>c</plaats>
        <email>c</email>
    </profiel>
    <profiel>
        <voornaam>c</voornaam>
        <achternaam>c</achternaam>
        <adres>c</adres>
        <postcode>cL</postcode>
        <plaats>c</plaats>
        <email>c</email>
    </profiel>
</profielen>
```

I can select 6 checkboxes, the more are selected the more it filters. If I select firstname, only a,b and the first person with the name c can stay and the second one will be ignored.

Now I have this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('/xampp/htdocs/UploadifyZWP/uploads/profiel.xml');
//Load the xml file into an array

$myArray = $_REQUEST['checkboxarray'];
//Contains the selected value (firstname = 0,lastname = 1 etc..)

if(count($myArray) <1){
    //If $myArray is empty it means no checkboxes are selected and there will be no filtering
    count($xml);
}else{
    $fields = $myArray;
    //If at least one field is selected, this code runs:
    switch(count($myArray)){
        case 1: 
            //One checkbox selected

            //Array where the profiles go withouth duplicates
            $profile = array();
            $passed = 0;
            $teller = 0;

            //Loops through all the profiles in the xml array
            while($passed < count($xml)){
                $add = false;

                //Checks for all the selected values, 1 checkbox is selected so only 0 (firstname) is selected and goes into $field
                foreach($fields as $field){
                    if(count($profile) < 1){
                        //If profile is empty, add the first profile from the xml array
                        $add = true;    
                    }else {
                        if($profile[$teller][$field] != $xml->profiel[$teller][$field])
                        {
                            $add = true;
                            break;

                        }else{
                            $teller++;
                            $passed++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($add = true){
                    //toevoegen
                    $profile[$teller] = $xml->profiel[$teller];
                    $teller++;
                    $passed++;  
                }
            }
            echo count($profile);
            print_r($profile);

            break;
        case 2:                         
            break;  
        case 3:                         
            break;  
        case 4:                         
            break;  
        case 5:                         
            break;  
        case 6:                         
            break;  
        default: echo "error";
    }


}
```

So I put all the correct profiles in $profile array and the duplicate will be ignored. Now for testing I print the array profiles to see if it did what it should do, but the outcome is not what I was looking for. The first one (a) will be added to $profiles, the second one (b) will not, the third one (c) is added again and the fourth (duplicate(d)) is not. Now if I add 2 more profiles (e,f), e will be added and f will not. Now I have troubles installing a debugger so I don't see where it is going wrong. I also get an error that says:

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 1 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\UploadifyZWP\ontdubbelen.php** on line **37**

And

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 3 in **C:\xampp\htdocs\UploadifyZWP\ontdubbelen.php** on line **37**

Does anyone see where it is going wrong and why?

Comment: You have `count($xml);` if `$myArray` is empty but that isn't actually setting anything, it's just internally counting it.

Comment: Ok but that should not effect my code right? As it does not goes there after I click one?

Comment: You're right, maybe the answer below is closer :)

Comment: You are not specifying which line is line 37.  Your cases can be formatted as `case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: break;`.  It's just nicer to read (insert line breaks appropriately; these comments don't display line breaks).  You're also using an assignment `$add=true` instead of the comparison operator in one of your if statements.  Your `$xml->profiel` is misspelled.  I don't know if your `$xml` array also contains that misspelling.  Help yourself and debug further.  Put statements like `echo 'Incrementing teller'` in your code to figure out what blocks your code is going to.

Answer (score 0):

On this line `if($profile[$teller][$field] != $xml->profiel[$teller][$field])` you have specified a third level of a multidimensional array but your data has only 2 levels as shown below.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [voornaam] => a
    [achternaam] => a
    [adres] => a
    [postcode] => a
    [plaats] => a
    [email] => a
)
```

Try this instead

```
if($profile[$teller] != $xml->profiel[$teller])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with this code, but the main one is that some of the logic in it is flawed.

I'll start by saying that the if statement `if($add = true)` will always return true, since you are *assigning* rather than *comparing*. You need to use `if ($add == true)` to perform a comparison.

Other than that, it's quite hard to say exactly what you're doing wrong, because it is a general failure in logic. The main issue comes down to the fact that, on the second iteration of your while loop (starting `while($passed < count($xml))`), the `$profile` array contains one element at index 0, (meaning that `count($profile) < 1` returns `false`, but the value of `$teller` is now `1`, since you incremented it in the first iteration. You then try to compare the value of `$profile[$teller][$field]`, which fails, because there is no offset of `1` in your `$profile` array.

**Edit**

To check for the existence of an index in an array, you can use `isset`, for example

```
if (isset($profile[$teller]))
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your reaction but lets say $profile is just empty, ingoring my code for a second. And I have to check if the first profile from my $xml does not already exist in $profile, how do I achieve this? I assumed that if you said something like this: if $profile[0][0] does not exist (and it does not exist ofcourse because the array is empty) that I could just add my first profile from $xml.

Comment: Expanded my answer to include advice on how to check if an index exists in an array