# Array instead of SimpleXMLElement Object in array PHP?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, object

I was wondering how to add XML content into a normal array, withouth adding it as a object. For example, I have this XML:

```
<example>
   <n1>
       <1>I am one</1>
       <2>I am two</2>
   </n1>

   <n2>
       <1>I am one</1>
       <2>I am two</2>
   </n2>

   <n3>
       <1>I am one</1>
       <2>I am two</2>
   </n3>
</example>
```

I add the XML to a variable:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('xlmfile');
```

Now, I create an empty erray:

```
$exarray = array();
```

Now, when I want to add n3 to $exarray, I can do something like this:

```
array_push($exarray,$xml[2]);
```

And now, when you print_r($exarray) , you see this:

```
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [n1] => I am one [n2] => I am two
```

So, this is a object that has been added to $exarray, but lets say you don't want to add an object to $exarray but an array (nr3 = index 2), how could you add nr3 as an array to $exarray? Also, if you eventually want $exarray to be something like this:

```
[0] => ( [n1] => I am one [n2] => I am two )
[1] => ( [n1] => I am one [n2] => I am two )
[2] => ( [n1] => I am one [n2] => I am two )

Echo $exarray[0][1] to return: I am two
```

is that possible?

Comment: *Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'* - Please post only working examples. Also [which of the *many* existing Q&A that deal with turning simplexml into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+simplexml+to+array) didn't work for you? And why? Reference each one of them you've tried so far and *outline detailed* which part of them do not work for you and what hinders you to change them to fit your needs?

Comment: Also your question sounds a bit like a replacement for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16936389/undefined-offset-php-array not getting an answer there. It's probably one step into the right direction to make it more broad but on the other hand, you could also try to improve your previous question to more specifically make the concrete problem you run into more visible. That might turn it into a better programming question and will give you a more useful answer.

Comment: I was not sure if changing a question would also bring it back up.

Comment: It does for those users who have ordered questions by activity. However asking a "new" question just to get more attention is hurting the site and working contrary to get good answers for everybody. Please don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible - 
You can do

> $array =
>   json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);

to get the xml in the array format and then fetch data from the array

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

 foreach ($xml->n1 as $element) {   
       foreach($element as $val) {    
            echo "$val";   
       } 
  }
```

and change the foreach to assign the values to an array with a counter.